# Showing div while hovering over image

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to enlarge an image when hovering over it as well as showing a div with text while hovering over that image. The enlarging works, but showing the other div doesn't.

```
<div id="punt1">
    <div id="puntnaam1" class="puntnaam">Ieplaan</div>
    <img class="punt"src="ieplaan1.jpg">
</div>
```

For CSS I used:

```
.punt{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.puntnaam{
    display: none;
}

.punt:hover{
    transform: scale(3);
}

.punt:hover .puntnaam{
    display: block;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You are checking for hover over en element which has both the classes "punt" and "puntnaam" which doesn't exist. I would recommend using javascript for the desired effect and having a function that triggers on the "hover" event, that performs both tasks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't select previous siblings or parent elements in the DOM with CSS. You can only select next siblings or child elements.

e.g., if you changed your code to this:

```
<div id="punt1">
    <img class="punt"src="ieplaan1.jpg">
    <div id="puntnaam1" class="puntnaam">Ieplaan</div>
</div>
```

Then your selector could look like this:

```
.punt:hover + .puntnaam{
    display: block;
}
```

Because now the `<div>` is the next sibling after `<img>`

See: [Is there a "previous sibling" CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector)

Comment: As skyline3000 was typing this I was creating this for you https://jsfiddle.net/399j5e03/ which is the exact same as stated...

Answer (score 0):

You cant do something like that

```
.punt:hover .puntnaam{
    display: block;
}
```

its not working that way in CSS cause puntnaam is already hidden,
You can use simple jQuery code to solve it

```
$(".punt").hover(function() {
$("#puntnaam1").show();
 });
```